# Stopping a CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have the following code which animates the image class while hovering over the container div. However, if the image is mid-animation and the user stops hovering the animation is paused – which looks sort of weird.

Is there a way to stop or revert a CSS animation to its static state?

```
.image{
    animation-play-state: paused;
    }

#container:hover .image{
    animation-play-state: running;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a screenshot of the image before the animation play perhaps?
    .image1{
    background-image: "yourimage"
    }
    #container:hover .image{
    animation-play-state: running;
    }

And set image1 as your static image and keep your hover as the animated. It's not a fail proof, but should work in theory.

Comment: Breaking it up into two classes, one static and one animated, worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped =D